# What does it mean? Python Crash Course

Tags: python, error-handling, crash, syntax-error

im new to programming. I just want to know what does user_info represent, what does user.items() represent and user_info['first'] represent.

Why does user_info in users.items(): represent the keys? Do we have to use this words to show the keys?

```
users ={
'aeinstein' : {'first' : 'albert','last' : 'einstein','location' : 'princeton'},
'mcurie':{'first':'marie','last' : 'curie' ,'location' : 'paris' }}

for username, user_info in users . items() :
    print("\nUsername:" + username)
    full_name = user_info[ 'first' ] + " " + user_info['last']
    location = user_info[ 'location' ]
    
    print("\tFull name: " + full_name. title())
    print("\tLocation : " + location.title())
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: ```.items()``` will give the key as well as the value of the dictionary

Comment: Please take the effort to copy paste the code here.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question!

Comment: Okay, sorry @Sujay, i don't know the culture here. I  will post my code here next time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if `user` and `user_info` are `Dict` (dictionary), and since the information within them is stored as a key, value pair `{k : v}` you either have to call `user.items()`, which will return a `list` containing key, value tuples like `(k, v)`. (to get the keys - `user.keys()` and for values - `user.values()`)

Also, you can search for a given value when you have the key, so `user_info['first']` would likely be searching for whatever information is under the `first` key in said dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the code does.

```
users ={
'aeinstein' : {'first' : 'albert','last' : 'einstein','location' : 'princeton'},
'mcurie':{'first':'marie','last' : 'curie' ,'location' : 'paris' }}

for username, user_info in users . items() :
    print("\nUsername:" + username)
    full_name = user_info[ 'first' ] + " " + user_info['last']
    location = user_info[ 'location' ]
    
    print("\tFull name: " + full_name. title())
    print("\tLocation : " + location.title())
```

Output:

```
Username:aeinstein
        Full name: Albert Einstein
        Location : Princeton

Username:mcurie
        Full name: Marie Curie
        Location : Paris
```

`.items()` returns the key as well as the values. Also, `user_info` is a dictionary. Now, we can either use `user_info.get()` or `user_info[]` can be used. So, here, you are fetching the value of that key.

Example:

```
for username, user_info in users.items() :
    print(username,user_info)
```

Output: You can see that it fetched the as well as keys. For only values:
it's `users.values()` and for keys, `users.keys()` is correct

```
aeinstein {'first': 'albert', 'last': 'einstein', 'location': 'princeton'}
mcurie {'first': 'marie', 'last': 'curie', 'location': 'paris'}
```

`user_info['first']`  fetched the value of the `'first'` key. Here, the value is `albert`, hence, it will print `albert.`
`full_name = user_info[ 'first' ] + " " + user_info['last']`. This is string concatenation.

Comment: Ok thank you sujay! May I know how do you make your code text in grey?

Comment: Just add a '`' 3 times. It is there above the tab key